# "Cope with" or "cope up with"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I want to learn the difference between "cope with" and "cope up with". Is the second one wrong or in use? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You either "put up with" something or "cope with" it.  The two mean roughly the same thing, outside of a woodworking shop.

Answer (score 3):

“Cope with” is the correct usage. I can’t think of an instance in which “cope up with” would be correct.

However, “put up with” is a (rather informal) phrase with a meaning similar to “cope with.” Sounds like the second phrase in your question is a mashup of both. You should use either “cope with” or “put up with” depending upon the specific tone and connotation you’re aiming for.